# new line using string replace

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I have problems with getting data from mysql database.Let's say that I have text like this in mysql table:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.

Suspendisse lobortis sit amet est in dapibus. Cras in dui diam.
```

This new line makes the problem.

I'm using jQuery to echo data to auto creatinig div's.

Here's the code:

```
for(i = <?php echo $row; ?>; i > 0; i--){
    count = 1;
    <?php
        while($col = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
        {
            $cols[] = $col;
        }
        foreach($cols as $col){
    ?>
    $("#text"+count+"").text("<?php echo $col['post'] ?>");
    $("#username"+count+"").text("<?php echo $col['username'] ?>");
    count++;
    <?php } ?>
}
```

I've tried to remove new line or to replace it with `<br>` using string replace like `str_replace("\n", '<br />', $col['post']);` but it didn't work. I've also tried many other codes and nothing worked for me.

Thanks for suggestions

Comment: Ouch, my eyes, what are you trying to do?

Comment: `nl2br()`? http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php

Comment: Also that jQuery `text()` function you show would not create any new elements at all.  It just reads or sets the content within the given element(s) indicated by the selector. That spaghetti code is a nightmare.  Why not just inject all you DB content into a javascript array or object literal once and then use that data structure to create your elements.

Comment: i have my doubts about the way you're mixing PHP and JS, but FYI, when you're iterating backwards you don't need all three parameters in your `for`, you can just do.. `for(i = <?php echo $row; ?>; i--;){`

Comment: @Mike Brant I know but it's just a part of the code because the problem is in that part

Comment: @user6332126 And likely the problem is in that part of the code because it is a nightmare to read and maintain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would be much better off seprating out your DB access logic and the client-side javascript stuff. You can also use `nl2br()` to convert newlines to `<br>`.  So something like this should work better.

```
<?php
    $rows = array();
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        // replace new lines in post with HTML breaks
        $row['post'] = nl2br($row['post']);
        $rows[] = $row;
    }
?>
<script>
// create javascript literal by echoing out JSON serialization of $rows from PHP
var dbRows = <?php echo json_encode($rows); ?>;
// iterate through DB records and create elements
$.each(dbRows, function(index, row) {
    $('<div class="text">').text(row.post).appendTo('#someTargetElement');
    $('<div class="username">').text(row.username).appendTo('#someTargetElement');
});
</script>
```

A few changes from your approach include:

- Using `nl2br()` on retrieved data from DB to prepare for use in HTML.
- Providing better separation between PHP and javascript. This is done by actually making the DB data available in javascript to manipulate instead of just injecting throuhgout javasctipt.
- Actually creating a new div elements to append to the DOM. Your code did not do this at all
- Ditching the `#text*` anti-pattern.  What value do the id labels add?  Typically when using libraries like jQuery you want all items that are similar to have similar class so you can operate on them as a class.

Comment: Thank you for suggestion. I hadn't tried it jet but I hope it would work. You asked for id's... Well this is not the whole code. Id's are used just because I have to echo single row to single div. I didn't put all the code here because it's too big. It actually prepends div's as many rows are in DB. I also included the style right in `.prepend` because every new div has to have different position. Maybe you would understand me better if I tell you that I want to make something like this http://ispovijesti.ba . This is Balcan site and I've wanted to do something like this just for practice

Answer (score 0):

**The first**

If the string output to a textarea or pre tag, `\n` will make new line in string. If you don't want to have new line, just remove `\n`.

**The second**

If the string output to another HTML tags,  `<br>` will make new line, just remove it to stop go to new line.

**The third**

In PHP, you can have new line in long string by concat strings with const `PHP_EOL`. Ex: `"Hello" . PHP_EOL . "Wolrd"`

In jQuery, $.text() will put escaped string to elment's text node (the content), $.html() will insert raw html (as string) to document.

**The last**

Please don't put your PHP codes together Javascript.